# Heroku, Node.js, PostgreSQL error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

My Heroku app crash a week ago and I have been troubleshooting for 3 days with no success. Tried to change the connection code to ssl and also did some changes to `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf` files but no luck.

This is the error that keep coming up :

```
ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "", user "", database "", SSL off
    at /app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:182:24
    at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:194:14)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:134:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:308:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:289:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23) {
  name: 'SequelizeConnectionError',
  parent: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "52.206.229.39", user "pirotuslftnuae", database "d7q6mo0trncmiq", SSL off
      at Connection.parseE (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:614:13)
      at Connection.parseMessage (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:413:19)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:129:22)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:308:12)
      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:289:11)
      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23) {
    name: 'error',
    length: 167,
    severity: 'FATAL',
    code: '28000',
    detail: undefined,
    hint: undefined,
    position: undefined,
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: undefined,
    table: undefined,
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: undefined,
    file: 'auth.c',
    line: '496',
    routine: 'ClientAuthentication'
  },
```

---

```
 const db = new Sequelize({
      user: "name",
      password: "****",
      database: "databaseName",
      port: 5432,
      host: "localhost",
      ssl: true,
      dialect: 'postgres',
      dialectOptions: {
        "ssl": {"rejectUnauthorized": false}
      }
    });
```

---

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
  host  all             all             0.0.0.0/0                md5
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow rep
```

---

```
# - Connection Settings -

#listen_addresses = '*'         # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_director`enter code here`ie
```

---

Comment: The pg_hba you show does not seem to be the one in effect on the server you are trying to connect to.  You are probably editing the wrong file, or have not reloaded/restarted after your edit.

Comment: I used the following command to access the pg  =>                                                       sudo nano /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf    and
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf  . Is there any others ways to access it ???.  Also I restarted the the app many times.

Comment: It is the database, not the app server, that needs to be restarted.

Comment: yes I did , I restarted the database (postgresql) after making the changes in the pg file.

Comment: sudo service postgresql restart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solve my issue with this ssl code in my database file

```
let config

if (process.env.DATABASE_URL) {
  config = {
    logging: false,
    ssl: true,
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: {
        require: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      }
    }
  }
} else {
  config = {
    logging: false
  }
}

const db = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DATABASE_URL ||
    `postgres://localhost:5432/${databaseName}`,
  config
)
```